# Drupal trip and hotel reservation

Tags: bookings

Is there a Drupal module that would allow you to use custom tables for making hotel and trip bookings and reservations? In my project, I have to use a specific API from a third party tour operator for gathering data for the offers, and displaying them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the relation between the custom tables and the API?

Comment: Well, I would be using custom tables for storing data from the third party API.

Comment: Could you not just use nodes to represent the data from the API? Then you can use Feeds to help you import the data...

Comment: Could you be a little more specific, I'm fairly new to this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Look for booking / reservation modules. There are some that would be a good starting point for you.

[Rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms), [Simple Reservation](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_reservation), [Easy Booking](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_booking) and [Open Hotel](https://www.drupal.org/project/openhotel) are just a few worth trying.